# Is this a runner put out or a baseman interfering?

Tags: rules, baseball, officiating

**Situation:** there is a runner on first base. The first-baseman is standing on the line to second base, about four feet from first base.

The ball is hit toward first base and fair. As soon as the ball is hit the runner starts to second; the first baseman runs straight toward first base intending to play the ball.

The runner and first baseman collide two feet away from first base. **Is the runner put out, or has the baseman interfered with the runner?**

Answer (score 5):

According to Rule 6.01 (a) of [the official rules](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/downloads/y2016/official_baseball_rules.pdf), the runner would be out, assuming neither runner nor fielder was judged to have intentionally initiated contact.

Comment: Please note in the Comment section of Rule 6.01 (a) it indicates that "A runner who is adjudged to have hindered a
fielder who is attempting to make a play on a batted ball is out
whether it was intentional or not."